# Call webservice error in worklight

Tags: web-services, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

i've 1 webservice with .Net and return value like that:

```
<People>
<Person Name="Nick"/>
<Person Name="Nick"/>
</People>
```

And i've also folow this tutorial to call webservice in my worklight app [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/using_ibm_worklight_http_adapters_with_xml_services2?lang=en) .But i've got some error:

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Content is not allowed in prolog.",
      "Failed to parse the payload from backend (procedure: HttpRequest)"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Cache-Control": "private",
      "Connection": "Close",
      "Content-Length": "457",
      "Content-Type": "text\/plain; charset=utf-8",
      "Date": "Thu, 13 Jun 2013 02:47:56 GMT",
      "Server": "ASP.NET Development Server\/10.0.0.0",
      "X-AspNet-Version": "2.0.50727"
   },
   "responseTime": 0,
   "statusCode": 500,
   "statusReason": "Internal Server Error",
   "totalTime": 141,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

Here is config in myadapert.xml:

```
<protocol>http</protocol>
<domain>localhost</domain>
<port>3923</port>
<procedure name="getperson"/>
```

and here in config in  myadapter-impl.js:

```
function getperson() {
    var input = {
            method : 'get',
            returnedContentType : 'xml',          
            path : "/Service1.asmx/MyMethod"
        };
        return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Thanks for any help !

UPDATED

when i've change "returnedContentEncoding" xml to plain.i've got this error:

```
{
   "errors": [
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Cache-Control": "private",
      "Connection": "Close",
      "Content-Length": "457",
      "Content-Type": "text\/plain; charset=utf-8",
      "Date": "Thu, 13 Jun 2013 02:28:38 GMT",
      "Server": "ASP.NET Development Server\/10.0.0.0",
      "X-AspNet-Version": "2.0.50727"
   },
   "responseTime": 281,
   "statusCode": 500,
   "statusReason": "Internal Server Error",
   "text": "System.InvalidOperationException: Getperson Web Service method name is not valid.\n   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()\n   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)\n   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)",
   "totalTime": 313,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Content is not allowed in prolog" error is usually thrown by parser when your XML contains some characters before the first <?xml.....> element.

Two options here:

1. Try changing returnedContentType to "plain" so returned XML will not be parsed and you can see what exactly might be causing the problem
2. Try manually setting returnedContentEncoding property of invocation options

Comment: i've returnedContentType to "plain" and see the error but how to fix it ? you can see my error in UPDATED my question

Comment: As you can see now in the 'text' field,  the problem is occurring on your back end and not on WL. The backend returns text error message and this is the reason WL server failed to parse it as XML in the first place. According to the error message "Getperson Web Service method name is not valid". Make sure that you're calling the correct URL.